# Set a property as reference to an object

Tags: javascript

I have a table that have a property named "recordsource" that will hold the name of the object that will fill the content of the table.

```
<table id="tbl" recordsource="myobj">
```

Now here are my functions:

```
var myobj;

function obj()
{
  this.code = new Array();
  this.name = new Array();
}

myobj = new obj();
myobj.code = ["a","b","c"];
myobj.name = ["apple","banana","carrot"];

function populate_table()
{
  mytable = document.getElementById("tbl");
  mytableobj = mytable.getAttribute("recordsource"); //this will return a string
  //my problem is how to reference the recordsource to the myobj object that have
  //the a,b,c array
}
```

Comment: you mean `myobj.recordsource = mytable.getAttribute('recordsource');`? Or do you mean you want the data in myobj to be stored in `mytable.setAttribute('recordsource',..`?

Comment: Agree with @bokonic. What is your goal here?

Comment: @bokonic Neither sir, but is that possible? I mean I will just put recordsource on the table tag as blank then setAttribute it to the actual object that I want to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `window[ mytableobj ]` it will return `myobj`

Comment: This will only work if all the objects are global (which probably isn't a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an object as a list of all the other objects that you want to be able to access.

```
...

var obj_list = {
  'myobj': myobj
};

function populate_table()
{
  mytable = document.getElementById("tbl");
  mytableobj = mytable.getAttribute("recordsource");

  // Then obj_list[mytableobj] == myobj

  obj_list[mytableobj].code[0] // Gives "a"
  obj_list[mytableobj].name[0] // Gives "apple"
}
```